# Using multiple SUMs in a Single SELECT like a foreach loop or CASE

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query that returns a break down of sales of a certain Product_ID.

I'd like to expand this query to include multiple Product_IDs.

Heres what I have that gives me 1 Product_ID:

```
SELECT
o.Customer_ID, o.CompanyName, cg.Category, o.Order_ID,
SUM(old.LineTotal) as TOTAL,
SUM(old.qty) as PID,
COUNT(o.Order_ID) as OIDs

FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Order_LineDetails old ON old.Order_ID = o.Order_ID
LEFT JOIN CustomerDetails cd ON o.Customer_ID = cd.Customer_ID
LEFT JOIN _CustomerCategory cg ON cg.Category_ID = cd.Category_ID

WHERE o.IsPENDING = 0
AND o.OrderPlaceServerTime >= '2012-1-1'
AND o.OrderPlaceServerTime <= '2012-9-1'
AND o.IsVOID = 0
AND old.Product_ID = '56789' 

GROUP BY o.Customer_ID
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I'm trying to add somthing to do more than 1 Product_ID and get the SUMs of them as well.

This is the idea I was looking at, but obviosley this does not work.

```
(CASE WHEN old.Product_ID = '56789' 
        SUM(old.LineTotal) as TOTAL_56789,
        SUM(old.qty) as PID_56789)
```

This would repeat based on how many products I was after.

Hopfully this makes sense.

Any suggestions?

EDIT::

Here's an example of what I'd like to get back.

[image]

Comment: can please give sum expected result?

Comment: Added the expected result, sorry I forgot that.

Comment: @Monty this could probably be done with prepared statements and a mock `PIVOT` but you should post the table structures of your tables and some sample data for each one so there is a clearer picture.  Or Even better create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the tables and data.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Basically you want pivot tables, but mysql does not support it. You can force it to some degree [writing your queries dinamically in your client application](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78). If you have more experience with stored procedures, you can try [the automatic version](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#523) .